# Calculated columns using Scalar Function in EF Code First

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, calculated-columns

I have a table for an Invoice and another for an InvoiceItem. An invoice can contain one or more Invoice Items. In our database, we have defined both Invoices and InvoiceItem with a Balance column. Is there a way to define the Balance column as a calculated column using Code First and **also** specify the SQL Server Scalar function to use?

I know I can setup the column as computed in Code First, but I do not see how to specify the SQL function to call using Fluent. Is this even possible?

Comment: I don't know how to resolve your issue but scalar functions are notoriously slow. Would probably be best if you can avoid it altogether.

Comment: I agree. We ultimately got rid of the calculated columns.